# REST API to create one or multiple resources?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api-design

The options I can think of are:

1

```
POST /book (object) - creates one book
POST /bulk/book (array) - creates multiple books
```

2

```
POST /book (object|array) - creates one or multiple books depending on the input type
```

3

```
POST /book (array) - expect an array every time, to create one book just have one in the array
```

Is there a recommendation?

Comment: When in doubt, find a company you trust and maybe use a similar approach. I.e. [salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_retrieve.htm)

Comment: I would go with 2 or 3

Answer (score 1):

I would go for 2 or 3 as well.

This is how I do it normally:

```
GET    /Books      => Get all books
GET    /Books/{id} => Get one book
POST   /Books      => Create new book
PUT    /Books/{id} => Updates all values of a book
PATCH  /Books/{id} => Updates/adds one or more value of a book
DELETE /Books/{id} => Deletes a given book
```

To make it easier for small projects, sometimes I merge Post, Put and Patch all into POST.

Comment: Agreed with everything, but what do you do for "Create new bookS", specifically?

Comment: POST on /books with an array containing the books objects

Comment: I editet the response to use Books instead of Books, it is better practise to have the nous in plural

Answer (score 0):

My preference is towards 3, with 2 being runner up.

What I like is that regardless of how many books you want created, there is but one way to do so, and that is via `POST /book (array)`.

This simplifies things for clients in that they don't have to use either a) a different endpoint b) a different data type depending on the number of books to be created. Need a book created? Perfect, there is one easy way to do so.

In the end, I see that as simplifying documentation, testing, and overall use.